# Three.js error - 'Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem using WebGL in Google Chrome, with Three.js. I'm trying to load an object and then perform a rotation on it, but get an error reported. The object loads fine but reports many of the same error. I've researched the problem and understand that it might be to do with asynchronous loading of objects, but I just can't figure out how this applies to mine.

The general format of my code is a switch statement:

```
case n:
loader = new OBJLoader();
loader.load('url', function(obj) {
    scene.add(obj);
});
rotate();
break;
```

Which then goes to the `rotate()` function of form:

```
function rotate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(rotate);
        obj.rotation.x += 0.5;
        obj.rotation.y += 0.5;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Both obj and loader are declared as global variables at the top of my code.

I'd really appreciate any help as I've been stuck for a while. Thanks

Comment: It's my first question on Stack Overflow, so I don't understand the down-vote. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `loader.load()` is asynchronous; meaning that its callback will be called when the `url` is fetched. Also meaning that the `rotate` will be called well before the callback function(thats why you get undefined `obj` in `rotate`) . If you move the `rotate` inside the `load` then you will not get the error.

Comment: @gaitat Thank you so much!